# Action firing, but reducer is not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Been struggling with this one for a while any help appreciated. With the below code it looks like the action fires successfully, but the reducer does not. No values are updated in redux store for rooms, but can confirm redux store is setup correctly and works fine for all my user actions and reducers.

I'm firing a function within a component `getRoom('someId)`, passing along an id which then does a fetch and returns the result. Upon getting that result I'm dispatching a redux action `saveRoom(res)`.

```
getRoom('someId')
            .then(res => {
                saveRoom(res);
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('Error', e));
```

Get room is just a fetch:

```
// Get room by id
export const getRoom = (roomId) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/room/read/${roomId}`, {
        method: "GET"
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err))
};
```

Save room is a simple action. I can see it is being called and fired correctly in my console log.

```
import {SAVE_ROOM} from "./types";

export const saveRoom = (data) => {
    console.log('Saving Room.', data);
    return {
        type: SAVE_ROOM,
        payload: data
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem like my reducer is firing at all. I have a console log to check but nothing returns in the console, and the redux store does not update.

```
import { SAVE_ROOM } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = { loading: true };

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('Save room reducer. Payload is: ', action.payload)
    switch (action.type) {
        case SAVE_ROOM:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                room: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I have also ensured that the reducers are combined and can confirm they're present using redux tools

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import userReducer from "./userReducer";
import roomReducer from "./roomReducer ";

export default combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    room: roomReducer 
});
```

Comment: You need to dispatch the return value of `saveRoom`

Comment: do you mean like so? I tried but it's not working either - unless I'm doing something wrong?

export const saveRoom = (data) => dispatch => {
    console.log('Saving Room.', data._id);
    dispatch({
        type: SAVE_ROOM,
        payload: data
    })
}

Comment: Something like that. It should be: `mapDispatchToProps({ saveRoom })` and then use `this.props.saveRoom(res)` instead of just `saveRoom(res)`.

Comment: @Titus I'm using redux hooks useDispatch and useSelector instead of the old map way

Comment: In that case, it should be `const dispatch = useDispatch()` and then: `dispatch(saveRoom(res))`

Comment: Yes, sorry I literally just got that as you typed it! haha thank you - all working.

Answer (score 0):

`const dispatch = useDispatch()`
and then
`dispatch(saveRoom(res))`